# How to display custom page when a user requests a folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, directory

How can you do that when the user requests a folder, for example: http://site.net/folder1/, then show him the custom page?

Not this: http://goo.gl/bbhVL (url shortener)

Comment: Do you mean Error Handling?

Comment: Yes!) My ErrorController catches this error, but then IIS still shows this page.

Comment: Here you go, try this : http://habrahabr.ru/post/128315/

Comment: Неа, это не совсем то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1):

You can custom controller to handle invalid url's and then display custom view. 
You need to modify web.config to tell which controller handles the 404

Check this [Handle Errors in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281418/How-to-handle-errors-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Comment: This doesn't correct the error that is shown when a user requests a directory

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found the solution, but I think that this is not the best option. For example, when an exception is triggered, and it shows a page with an custom error, then this link `@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "link" }` is transformed into: `htttp://hostname/error`. But when i remove `new { @class = "link" }`, the link becomes normal.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="403"/>
        <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="14" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/accessdenied" />
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode='ExecuteURL' path="/error/notfound" />
        <remove statusCode="500"/>
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode='ExecuteURL' path="/error/servererror" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```